# parse pdf metadata date using pdfminer

Tags: python, date, parsing, pdf, metadata

I'm trying to get the metadata for a pdf file

```
from pdfminer3.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer3.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
fp = open('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/storage/jdghosh_sap@rediffmail.com.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
print(doc.info[0]["CreationDate"])
print(doc.info[0]["ModDate"])
```

OUTPUT

```
b"D:20140706114446+05'30'"
b"D:20140706114446+05'30'"
```

How can I parse this data into a python date ?

Comment: related: [Convert CreationTime of PDF to a readable format in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16503075/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a little function that converts it:

```
from pdfminer3.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer3.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

def convertPdfDatetime(pd):
    from datetime import datetime
    dtformat = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    clean = pd.decode("utf-8").replace("D:","").split('+')[0]
    return datetime.strptime(clean,dtformat)

fp = open('/home/prtjohanson/test.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
pdf_creation_date = doc.info[0]["CreationDate"]
print(pdf_creation_date)
print(convertPdfDatetime(pdf_creation_date))
```

For some reason on my linux machine, I get no suffix staring with the + at the end of the datetime string, I suspect it has something to do with a timezone perhaps, or it may depend on how the pdf file itself was created.

In any case, the code above should cover both cases.

Comment: `+05'30'` represents the timezone which here means UTC+05:30 (that is IST). In `clean`, you need the text before the first `+` or `-` since `-05'30'` is a valid timezone too.

Comment: Like `datetime.strptime(pd.decode("utf-8").replace("D:", "").replace("'", ""), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z")`. Basically replacing the `'` in the timezone and using `%z` for the new `±HHMM`