# pdf.getDocumentInfo date format

Tags: python, datetime, pypdf

I am using pypdf2's function for extracting document info. The results are something like this but I am unable to interpret the creation date format. What are the last few digits representing?

```
pdf.documentInfo
[Output]: {'/Creator': 'Rave (http://www.nevrona.com/rave)',
           '/Producer': 'Nevrona Designs',
           '/CreationDate': 'D:20060301072826' }
```

and at one point I also saw this:

```
CreationDate': "D:20170920114835+02'00'"
```

how can I read or convert it into a normal date time readable format?

Comment: Looks like `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`. +02 is perhaps UTC offset?

Comment: @mportes I wouldn't say perhaps - it's a UTC offset for sure; just the single quotes there are confusing / unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can clean & parse like

```
from datetime import datetime

CreationDate = "D:20170920114835+02'00'"

dt = datetime.strptime(CreationDate.replace("'", ""), "D:%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z")

# UTC offset is set correctly:
print(dt)
# 2017-09-20 11:48:35+02:00
print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 11, 48, 35, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

...which I think is more straight forward than the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503075/convert-creationtime-of-pdf-to-a-readable-format-in-python) shows.